# Issue with the calendar app in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I am not able to see Accept/Decline option for the calendar meetings in Calendar app in my iPhone.

How to do i Accept/Decline meetings in calendar app in my iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

Try “Inbox”, on the bottom right.